# Gitlab не возвращает список коммитов через REST API

Tags: rest, gitlab

Всем привет.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, один и тот же REST запрос к разным репозиториям Gitlab`а ведёт себя по-разному.
`http://${GITLAB_URL}/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/repository/commits?ref_name=${BRANCH}`
Один и тот же пользователь, один и тот же сервер. Но на одном репозитории выдаёт список коммитов по веткам, а на другом `[]` и всё.

Answer (score 0):

Все зависит от доступности данного репозитория для пользователя, попробуйте создать [приватный токен](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html) и добавить его в header, предварительно проверив доступность через UI

```
curl --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "http://${GITLAB_URL}/api/v4/projects/${project_id}/repository/commits?ref_name=${BRANCH}"
```